# Forward header to implementations

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, apollo-federation, gqlgen

I'm building a graphql api with gqlgen and apollo federation as a gateway.

in gqlgen, I have three services: static page, accounts, auth.

And I'm using apollo federation as a gateway.

For the auth section I need to get Authorization header like `r.Header.Get("Authorization")` in middleware. But it is empty.

How can I pass headers from apollo federation gateway to gqlgen server?